# In Kali, when I try to install some packages I get the deletion of other packages

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I am having an issue with the installation of some packages with kali linux. After introducing the command for an installation(not with every single one, but it happens) I get a suggestion where I'm suggested to delete packages while installing others and update some.
If I introduce (Y) the pc just breaks down, if I introduce (n) I don't get the installation of the package.

It happened to me even with a brand new installed OS.

The problem looks like this.
I enter the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install protonvpn-cli
```

And as a response I get:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
(...)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
(...)
The following packages will be upgraded:
(...)
270 upgraded, 47 newly installed, 75 to remove and 1402 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,233 kB/344 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB disk space will be freed.
Would you like to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: The title says Debian, the content says Kali - which is it? Secondly, proton [secure email providers + VPN etc] provide an installation process - see https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-client/ You wouldn't use `apt` to install the VPN software.

Comment: You deleted the images, but forgot to replace it with the actual text. @JeremyBoden yes the step in installing protonvpn on Debian like systems installs a package which adds a repository (this one: `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main`
 -> https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/ ) . I guess it was tested on the 4 debian-like dists written in the doc, not on Kali.

Comment: Thanks @A.B. The old way involved downloading a .DEB file from the site and running `Gdebi` to install it which was not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Installing some packages might lead to uninstalling others that conflict with it in some way (they include the same files) or they have dependencies that clash (one needs a newer version of a library than the other, for example). Without digging into it, it is impossible to know what is going on. In any case, such massive changes are probably caused by trying to force installation of e.g. packages from a different version of the system or of a related, but diverged, distribution.

Unless you *really* know what you are doing, refrain from it (breakage is very probable). And if you know what you are doing, you won't do it. If you really need the package, consider compiling from source (or better still, learn how to create your own packages).